# Multi-field, multi-word, match without query_string

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, tire

I would like to be able to match a multi word search against multiple fields where every word searched is contained in **any** of the fields, any combination. The catch is I would like to **avoid using** query_string.

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/index/document/1" -d '{"id":1,"firstname":"john","middlename":"clark","lastname":"smith"}'
curl -X POST "http://localhost:9200/index/document/2" -d '{"id":2,"firstname":"john","middlename":"paladini","lastname":"miranda"}'
```

I would like the search for 'John Smith' to match only document 1. The following query does what I need but I would rather avoid using query_string in case the user passes "OR", "AND" and any of the other advanced params.

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/index/_search?per_page=10&pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "john smith",
      "default_operator": "AND",
      "fields": [
        "firstname",
        "lastname",
        "middlename"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: I keep coming to this question over and over and over again. Great, evergreen question!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html), but it doesn't perform in quite the way you would like.

Compare the output of [validate](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-validate.html) for `multi_match` vs `query_string`.

`multi_match` (with operator `and`) will make sure that ALL terms exist in at least one field:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_validate/query?pretty=1&explain=true'  -d '
{
   "multi_match" : {
      "operator" : "and",
      "fields" : [
         "firstname",
         "lastname"
      ],
      "query" : "john smith"
   }
}
'

# {
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 1,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "explanations" : [
#       {
#          "index" : "test",
#          "explanation" : "((+lastname:john +lastname:smith) | (+firstname:john +firstname:smith))",
#          "valid" : true
#       }
#    ],
#    "valid" : true
# }
```

While `query_string` (with default_operator `AND`) will check that EACH term exists in at least one field:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_validate/query?pretty=1&explain=true'  -d '
{
   "query_string" : {
      "fields" : [
         "firstname",
         "lastname"
      ],
      "query" : "john smith",
      "default_operator" : "AND"
   }
}
'

# {
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 1,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "explanations" : [
#       {
#          "index" : "test",
#          "explanation" : "+(firstname:john | lastname:john) +(firstname:smith | lastname:smith)",
#          "valid" : true
#       }
#    ],
#    "valid" : true
# }
```

So you have a few choices to achieve what you are after:

1. Preparse the search terms, to remove things like wildcards, etc, before using the `query_string`
2. Preparse the search terms to extract each word, then generate a `multi_match` query per word
3. Use `index_name` in your mapping for the name fields to index their data into a single field, which you can then use for search.  (like your own custom `all` field):

As follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "test" : {
         "properties" : {
            "firstname" : {
               "index_name" : "name",
               "type" : "string"
            },
            "lastname" : {
               "index_name" : "name",
               "type" : "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "firstname" : "john",
   "lastname" : "smith"
}
'

curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "name" : {
            "operator" : "and",
            "query" : "john smith"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "firstname" : "john",
#                "lastname" : "smith"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.2712221,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "VJFU_RWbRNaeHF9wNM8fRA",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.2712221,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 33
# }
```

Note however, that `firstname` and `lastname` are no longer searchable independently.  The data for both fields has been indexed into `name`.

You could use [multi-fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html) with the `path` parameter to make them searchable both independently and together, as follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "test" : {
         "properties" : {
            "firstname" : {
               "fields" : {
                  "firstname" : {
                     "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "any_name" : {
                     "type" : "string"
                  }
               },
               "path" : "just_name",
               "type" : "multi_field"
            },
            "lastname" : {
               "fields" : {
                  "any_name" : {
                     "type" : "string"
                  },
                  "lastname" : {
                     "type" : "string"
                  }
               },
               "path" : "just_name",
               "type" : "multi_field"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'

curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "firstname" : "john",
   "lastname" : "smith"
}
'
```

Searching the `any_name` field works:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "any_name" : {
            "operator" : "and",
            "query" : "john smith"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "firstname" : "john",
#                "lastname" : "smith"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.2712221,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "Xf9qqKt0TpCuyLWioNh-iQ",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.2712221,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 11
# }
```

Searching `firstname` for `john AND smith` doesn't work:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "firstname" : {
            "operator" : "and",
            "query" : "john smith"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [],
#       "max_score" : null,
#       "total" : 0
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 2
# }
```

But searching `firstname` for just `john` works correctly:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/test/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "firstname" : {
            "operator" : "and",
            "query" : "john"
         }
      }
   }
}
'

# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "firstname" : "john",
#                "lastname" : "smith"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.30685282,
#             "_index" : "test",
#             "_id" : "Xf9qqKt0TpCuyLWioNh-iQ",
#             "_type" : "test"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.30685282,
#       "total" : 1
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 3
# }
```

Comment: I'm confused about why that first `multi_match` query is returning something. I assume that when you say "all terms" you mean "john" and "smith". It is not the case that "john" and "smith" both exist in the `first_name` field. And it is not the case that "john" and "smith" both exist in the `last_name` field.

Comment: @AdamZerner is above answer still valid? because when I execute the validate request for multi_match and query_string query, they both produce the same explanation ? I am using ES 7.10.2

Comment: @NishikantTayade I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: @AdamZerner No worries! I have posted the same on ES forum, will get back here if I get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I would rather avoid using query_string in case the user passes "OR", "AND" and any of the other advanced params.

In my experience, escaping the special characters with backslash is a simple and effective solution. The list can be found in the documentation http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package_description, plus AND/OR/NOT/TO.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use [cross_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_cross_fields_queries.html) type in `multi_match`

```
GET /_validate/query?explain
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query":       "peter smith",
            "type":        "cross_fields", 
            "operator":    "and",
            "fields":      [ "firstname", "lastname", "middlename" ]
        }
    }
}
```

Cross-fields take a term-centric approach. It treats all of the fields as one big field, and looks for each term in any field.

One thing to note though is that if you want it to work optimally, all fields analyzed should have the same analyzer (standard, english, etc.):

> For the cross_fields query type to work optimally, all fields should
>   have the same analyzer. Fields that share an analyzer are grouped
>   together as blended fields.
>
> If you include fields with a different analysis chain, they will be
>   added to the query in the same way as for best_fields. For instance,
>   if we added the title field to the preceding query (assuming it uses a
>   different analyzer), the explanation would be as follows:
>
> (+title:peter +title:smith) (   +blended("peter", fields: [first_name,
>   last_name])   +blended("smith", fields: [first_name, last_name]) )

Answer (score -1):

I think "match" query is what you are looking for:

"The match family of queries does not go through a “query parsing” process. It does not support field name prefixes, wildcard characters, or other “advance” features. For this reason, chances of it failing are very small / non existent, and it provides an excellent behavior when it comes to just analyze and run that text as a query behavior (which is usually what a text search box does)"

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/match-query.html