# What's the difference between query_string and multi_match?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

When running this queries:

```
{
  "query_string" : {
    "query" : "text",
    "fields": ["field1", "field2"]
  }
}
```

-

```
{
  "multi_match" : {
    "query" : "text",
    "fields": ["field1", "field2"]
  }
}
```

What is the difference? When to use one and when to use the other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[`query_string` supports Lucene syntax to interpret the text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html), where as [`multi_match` just attempts to match the given `"text"` against the listed fields' indexed values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html).

Query string is therefore far more powerful, but it can also lead to unexpected scenarios, such as where `/` may cause part of the string to be interpreted as a regular expression.

DrTech does a pretty excellent job demonstrating the two over [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15430238/706724).