# Is there a difference between "match" and "simple_query_string" if no special characters?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic Search 7.9

I'm searching a single field with a textbox exposed to users through a web UI.

```json
    {
        match: {
            body: {
                query: 'beer pretzels',
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm debating whether to use `simple_query_string` instead.

```json
    {
        simple_query_string: {
          query: 'beer pretzels',
        }
    }
```

My initial thought was to switch to `simple_query_string` if I detect special characters in the keywords. But now I wonder why I'd use `match` at all.

### My questions:

Are there any differences between `match` and `simple_query_string` for the simple case where the keywords contains no special characters?

Any reason why I would not use `simple_query_string` all the time?

Answer (score 1):

> Simple Query string returns documents based on a provided query
> string, using a parser with a limited but fault-tolerant syntax.

Refer this to get a [detailed explanation](https://dzone.com/articles/23-useful-elasticsearch-example-queries), which states that :

> The simple_query_string query is a version of the query_string query
> that is more suitable for use in a single search box that is exposed
> to users because it replaces the use of AND/OR/NOT with +/|/-,
> respectively, and it discards invalid parts of a query instead of
> throwing an exception if a user makes a mistake.

**It supports Lucene syntax to interpret the text, you can refer this [article](https://in.relation.to/2017/04/27/simple-query-string-what-about-it/) that gives detailed information about how simple query string works.**

> Match Query returns documents that match a provided text, number, date
> or boolean value. The provided text is analyzed before matching.

**Refer to this [ES documentation part](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-boolean) and this [blog](https://towardsdatascience.com/deep-dive-into-querying-elasticsearch-filter-vs-query-full-text-search-b861b06bd4c0), to understand how the match query works**

I have tried to run this below search query using both simple query string and match query:

**Index Data**

```
{
    "content":"foo bar -baz"
}
```

**Search Query using simple query string:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "fields": [ "content" ],
      "query": "foo bar -baz"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_63937563",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,      <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "content": "foo bar -baz"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search Query using match query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": {
        "query": "foo bar -baz"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_63937563",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.8630463,    <-- note this
        "_source": {
          "content": "foo bar -baz"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Please refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37690741/10348758) that explains the difference between `multi_match` and `query_string`

Comment: Thank you. I am interested in the case where the keywords contain no special characters. Is there any difference between match and simple_query_string in that case?

Comment: @KevinLawrence As far as I know there will be no difference in the score when querying on keywords containing no special characters by using `match` or `simple query string`.
I have tested it locally also, when I search for `"content": "foo bar baz"`, the score generated by both the queries is same i.e. `0.8630463`.

Comment: @KevinLawrence please go through my updated answer, and please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer, if it helped you resolve your queries :)